# Does TTBR1 changes after linux kernel init (ARMv8-A)?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, mmu

Does TTBR1 changes after linux kernel init (ARMv8-A)?

As I understood Linux uses TTBR0 and TTBR1 for virtual memory managment. TTBR0 is physical address of translation table for user-space, TTBR1 is the same for kernel space.

Would I be right if I say that TTBR0 changes every context switch, TTBR1 stays the same all the time after kernel init time?

Can loading/unloading of kernel modules impact on TTBR1?

Comment: Yes, actually it changes. In this patch: https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/1510942921-12564-4-git-send-email-will.deacon@arm.com/ Will Deacon set up TCR.A1 MMU configuration bit what means ASID value is stored in TTBR1 (but not in TTBR0). As I can see in gdb only ASID bits changes on context switch.